# SwiftUI NavigationStack pop to root

Tags: swiftui

How can I pop to `root` in the new `NavigationStack` in IOS 16 while using many `NavigationLink`'s inside other `NavigationLink`?

Here is a solution for using the `NavigationLink(_ title, value: )`, but once I try to build out `Views` with more `NavigationLink`'s inside the `.navigationDestination` the `NavigationStack` gives the error `A navigationDestination for MyApp.DataObject was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used.`

```
struct DataObject: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct ContentView8: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Text("Root Pop")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
            
            NavigationLink("Click Item", value: DataObject.init(name: "Item"))
            
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .navigationDestination(for: DataObject.self) { course in
                Text(course.name)
                NavigationLink("Go Deeper", value: DataObject.init(name: "Item"))
                Button("Back to root") {
                    path = NavigationPath()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the error from attempting the above approach. Adding the View within the `NavigationLink` that has another `NavigationLink` seems to give the error.

```
struct NavObj: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct ContentView881: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack() {
            NavigationLink(destination: T0121(test: 1), label: {Text("Click")})
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct T0121: View{
    @State var test: Int
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(String(test))
            NavigationLink(value: NavObj.init(name: "Next"), label: {Text("Click")})
            .navigationDestination(for: NavObj.self) { item in
                T0121(test: 2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I have many views within other views I assume I should stick with `NavigationLink(destination, label)`, but the following logic to pop to root which works for `NavigationView` does not work on the `NavigationStack`:

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView(test: 1, isActive: $isActive), isActive: $isActive, label: {Text("Click")})
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct TestView: View{
    @State var test: Int
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(String(test))
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView(test: test+1, isActive: $isActive), label: {Text("Click")})
            Button(action: {
                isActive = false
            }, label: {
                Text("Root")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for making such a long question, I just wanted to make the issue very clear with plenty of examples. Thank you for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to handle pop-to-root in iOS 16, *is* to use a `NavigationStack` with a `path`, The problem seems to be that the `navigationDestination` modifier in your example is applied to the `NavigationLink` itself, it should be applied to the view at the top of the stack that contains the `NavigationLink` (e.g. `List`).

So you can fix your second example:

```
struct NavObj: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView881: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack() {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: T0121(test: 1), label: {Text("Click")})

            }
            .navigationDestination(for: NavObj.self) { item in
                T0121(test: 2)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct T0121: View{
    @State var test: Int
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(String(test))
            NavigationLink(value: NavObj.init(name: "Next"), label: {Text("Click")})
        }
    }
}
```